# How to set a default url in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, default-value

In my app users can list someone's instagram profile, but they would have to copy and paste the entire url in the form.

```
<%= f.url_field :url,required: true,label: "URL (required)" %>
```

How do i set the default url in my form as instagram.com/ so that they would only need to enter the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just ask for username and later in controller/form model remove `@` (and whole 'http://instagram.com/' prefix if someone pastes url instead of username)

```
<%= f.text_field :instagram_username, required: true, label: "instagram.com/" %>
```

Controller something like:

```
 obj = Model.new(model_params)
 if (username = params.dig(:some_model, :instagram_username))
   username = username.gsub(%r{https?://instagram.com/}, '').gsub(/^@/, '')
   obj.url = "https://instagram.com/#{CGI.escape username}"
 end
```